Pandas pyarrow types and sum aggfunc in pivot tables
I stumbled over the issue that the summation aggfunc in pandas behaves not as expected when using bool[pyarrow] instead of bool.
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': [False] * 12, 'index': [0, 1] * 6, 'cols': ['a', 'b', 'c'] * 4})
#     count  index cols
# 0   False      0    a
# 1   False      1    b
# 2   False      0    c
# 3   False      1    a
# 4   False      0    b
# 5   False      1    c
# 6   False      0    a
# 7   False      1    b
# 8   False      0    c
# 9   False      1    a
# 10  False      0    b
# 11  False      1    c

# Returns ints
# cols   a  b  c
# index
# 0      0  0  0
# 1      0  0  0
df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc=np.sum, columns='cols', index='index')
df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc='sum', columns='cols', index='index')
df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc=lambda x: x.sum(), columns='cols', index='index')

# Now change to pyarrow bools
df['count'] = df['count'].astype('bool[pyarrow]')

# Returns ints
# cols   a  b  c
# index
# 0      0  0  0
# 1      0  0  0
df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc=np.sum, columns='cols', index='index')
df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc='sum', columns='cols', index='index')

# Returns a boolean
# cols       a      b      c
# index
# 0      False  False  False
# 1      False  False  False
df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc=lambda x: x.sum(), columns='cols', index='index')

What is the reason for this behavior?
I am using pandas 2.2.0 and pyarrow 15.0.0.
Update: I found a pandas issue which describes a similar use case: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53030
Seems to be related to pandas internal handling of pyarrow types.
A possible workaround could be:
df.pivot_table(values='count', aggfunc=lambda x: x.astype(int).sum(), columns='cols', index='index')


Have you tried with the latest version of pandas and pyarrow?
